# Invoke-Command not returning anything

Tags: powershell, csv, arguments, invoke-command

I'm trying to run an executable on remote machines with variables supplied via a csv file.
The csv file looks like the following: (is made up of variables from querying the remote machines - no problem with that bit).

```
"Server","Command",                  "Arg1","Arg2","Arg3","FName"
Server1,C:\path\to\exe with spaces, /arg1, "arg2", arg3, filename
```

The issue is that I would like somehow to retain the "" around "Arg2", but import-csv strips them I believe..

The import code is:

```
Import-Csv $LogFolder\Machines.csv | ForEach-Object { 
  Invoke-Command ComputerName $_.Server  { 
    param($Command, $Arg1, $Arg2, $Arg3, $FName)
    $Command
  } -Args $_.Arg1, $_.Arg2, $_.Arg3, $_.FName
}
```

I've attempted putting the path to the executable in place of the $Command with &

```
Import-Csv $LogFolder\Machines.csv | ForEach-Object { 
  Invoke-Command ComputerName $_.Server  { 
    param($Command, $Arg1, $Arg2, $Arg3, $FName)
    & "C:\path\to\exe with spaces"
  } -Args $_.Arg1, $_.Arg2, $_.Arg3, $_.FName
}
```

The command seems to run & I get nothing back, but I am expecting to see a file on the remote server that doesn't appear...

Is there something I'm blindly missing in the above code?

Sorry, I'm still learning powershell & my google-fu isn't helping at the moment.. :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tested with this csv file,

```
"Server","Command",                  "Arg1","Arg2","Arg3","FName"
server,cmd, /c echo, test, this, <fullpath>\fname.txt
```

and executed it with this script.

```
Import-Csv $LogFolder | ForEach-Object { 
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.Server -ScriptBlock {
    param($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5)
    .  $arg1 $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString("$arg2 $arg3 $arg4 > $arg5")
  } -args $_.Command, $_.Arg1, $_.Arg2, $_.Arg3, $_.FName
}
```

**Issues with your script**

1. First obvious thing i saw was a missing - before `ComputerName`.
2. 2nd thing is, you are running an executable but not providing any arguments to it. Update your command and add the variables to it as well.
3. You need to understand that arguments passed to `Invoke-Command` have one to one mapping. You are defining 5 parameters within the function but only passing 4.

```
Import-Csv $LogFolder\Machines.csv | ForEach-Object { 
  Invoke-Command ComputerName $_.Server  { 
    param($Command, $Arg1, $Arg2, $Arg3, $FName)
    $Command
  } -Args $_.Arg1, $_.Arg2, $_.Arg3, $_.FName
       # $_.Arg1 -> Command
       # $_.Arg2 -> $Arg1
       # $_.Arg3 -> $Arg2 .. and so on.
}
```

I am using `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString` to combine all the parameters together. Since the purpose of this was to combine multiple strings into one to create a single string (without quotes outside of each element), this takes care of it.

You can use either `.` or `&` to invoke the command.

**Update for use of Quotes in your execution**

```
Import-Csv $LogFolder| ForEach-Object { 

# Limit the number of arguments sent via -args.
$Exe = $_.Command

# Use "" to parse it as " within your script.
$arguments = "$($_.arg1) $($_.arg2) ""$($_.arg3)"" > $($_.fname)"

  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.Server -ScriptBlock {
    param($command, $arguments)
    . $command $arguments
  } -args $exe, $arguments
}
```

Comment: Thank you! - I forgot the - before Computername but I had added it in in the code while posting!

Just one thing, do you know how I can inject quotes around $_.Arg2 at all?

Comment: I was able to print quotes when used within the script  (not the file itself). See update section

Comment: this is looking brilliant, many thanks...  I have simplified the $Exe, & hard coded the arg into the line so now I only need 2 arguments...

However, there is now a space between the parameters that I need to remove somehow..

$_.Command now contains spaces & args 1&2 in 1 line (Don't know why I didn't do that before as the 1st arg doesn't change)..

so now if I write-host shows "C:\path\to \exe" /arg1 /arg2 "arg3" arg4

All seems fine but I need to remove the space after /arg2 (which then comes from the csv) - is there a way to remove the space? Trim() isn't working?

Sorry..

Comment: $Exe = $_.Command

# Use "" to parse it as " within your script.
$arguments = """$($_.Arg3)"" $($_.Arg4)"
Write-Host $Exe $arguments
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.Server -Credential $CredItem -ScriptBlock {
    param($command, $arguments)
 & $Exe $arguments
  } -args $exe, $arguments
}

Shows: "C:\path\to \exe" Arg1 Arg2 "Arg3" Arg4
Needs: "C:\path\to \exe" Arg1 Arg2"Arg3" Arg4

Sorry, I've tried a few ways, moving it next to it, ("Arg3").Trim()

I think I need a few days of not looking at it really as I think I'm confusing myself..

Comment: @Alex if you have spaces then you want to put the variables in your script next to each other without spaces along with Trim().  `$arguments = """$($_.Arg3)""<Remove_Space_Here>$($_.Arg4)"`

Comment: Sorry - that's not working...

$arguments = """$($_.Arg3).Trim()""$($_.Arg4)"

Also tried & $Exe $arguments.Trim()
But now getting:
The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command
name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.

Comment: @Alex The point I made with this answer was that you cant use functions, like trim, outside of $() if its within quotes. Please place trim inside like `$($_.arg3.trim())` and try again

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
$arg1 = 'cmd'
$arg2 = '/c'
$arg3 = 'dir'
$server = 'comp001'
invoke-command -computername $server { param($a,$b,$c) 
  & $a $b $c} -args $arg1,$arg2,$arg3
```